# Why does the Twilio SDK not recognize a V2010 object as a child of Twilio\Version?

Tags: php, twilio-php

I rarely and randomly get the following error when sending a message with the `Twilio PHP SDK`. The error message doesn't make sense to me, because V2010 objects do extend the `Twilio\Version` abstract class.

> TypeError Twilio\InstanceContext::__construct(): Argument #1
> ($version) must be of type Twilio\Version, Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010
> given, called in
> /var/task/vendor/twilio/sdk/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/AccountContext.php
> on line 119

Here are the relevant files from the SDK:

[AccountContext.php](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/d32b96720d2b49ad65a1f0830b44991a662e119d/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/AccountContext.php)

[V2010.php](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/d32b96720d2b49ad65a1f0830b44991a662e119d/src/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010.php)

Comment: Welcome to SO!
I think you can improve your question a little bit, including (at least partially) your code here. Significantly, the AccountContext.php on line 119.

Comment: Thank you James. I've added the extra information you suggested.